# Proving the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality in a specific case

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the Euclidean norm $||(s,t)||=\sqrt{s^2+t^2}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfies the triangle inequality $||p+q||\le ||p||+||q||$.

Proof:

Let $(s_1,t_1),(s_2,t_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Consider $||(s_1,t_1) + (s_2,t_2)||^2$. Then $||(s_1,t_1) + (s_2,t_2)||^2 = \left(\sqrt{(s_1+s_2)^2+(t_1+t_2)^2}\right)^2=$

$(s_1+s_2)^2+(t_1+t_2)^2 = s_1^2+2s_1^2s_2^2+s_2^2 + t_1^2+2t_1^2t_2^2+t_2^2 = s_1^2 + t_1^2+2(s_1^2s_2^2+t_1^2t_2^2)+s_2^2+t_2^2$.

Now consider $\left(||(s_1,t_1)||+||(s_2,t_2)||\right)^2 = \left( \sqrt{s_1^2+t_1^2}+  \sqrt{s_2^2+t_2^2}\right)^2 =  $

$\left( \sqrt{s_1^2+t_1^2}\right)^2 +2 \sqrt{s_1^2+t_1^2}\cdot  \sqrt{s_2^2+t_2^2}+ \left(\sqrt{s_2^2+t_2^2}\right)^2 =$

$s_1^2+t_1^2 +2 \sqrt{(s_1^2+t_1^2)(s_2^2+t_2^2)}+s_2^2+t_2^2$.

Then by the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality $s_1^2s_2^2+t_1^2t_2^2\le  \sqrt{(s_1^2+t_1^2)(s_2^2+t_2^2)}$.

It follows that $s_1^2 + t_1^2+2(s_1^2s_2^2+t_1^2t_2^2)+s_2^2+t_2^2\le s_1^2+t_1^2 +2 \sqrt{(s_1^2+t_1^2)(s_2^2+t_2^2)}+s_2^2+t_2^2$,

$ \left(\sqrt{(s_1+s_2)^2+(t_1+t_2)^2}\right)^2\le \left( \sqrt{s_1^2+t_1^2}+  \sqrt{s_2^2+t_2^2}\right)^2 $,

$||(s_1,t_1) + (s_2,t_2)||^2\le \left(||(s_1,t_1)||+||(s_2,t_2)||\right)^2 $,

$||(s_1,t_1) + (s_2,t_2)||\le ||(s_1,t_1)||+||(s_2,t_2)||$.

Thus the Euclidean norm $||(s,t)||=\sqrt{s^2+t^2}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfies the triangle inequality $||p+q||\le ||p||+||q||$.

$\square$

I believe this proof works, but I have to prove that $s_1^2s_2^2+t_1^2t_2^2\le  \sqrt{(s_1^2+t_1^2)(s_2^2+t_2^2)}$

rather than just say "By the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality". There are plenty of examples of the proof of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, but I don't see how the left hand side, $s_1^2s_2^2+t_1^2t_2^2 = |\langle s_1^2+t_1^2),(s_2^2+t_2^2)\rangle |$?

Comment: Indeed, you cannot use the Cauchy Inequality as you did, which only gives you $s_1s_2+t_1t_2\le  \sqrt{(s_1^2+t_1^2)(s_2^2+t_2^2)}$. And there are some easy counterexample for instance $2^22^2+2^22^2>\sqrt{(2^2+2^2)(2^2+2^2)}$

Comment: actually, according to the proof, it must be $s_1s_2+t_1t_2 \le  \sqrt{(s_1^2+t_1^2)(s_2^2+t_2^2)}$, otherwise in one of the lines you cannot have $\sqrt{(s_1+s_2)^2+(t_1+t_2)^2}$